# Having trouble installing Linux Live CD on to a VirtualBox Hard Drive (install option is not working)

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, installation

I've built several Ubuntu ISO images using Ubuntu Builder which will run in VirtualBox as a Live CD, I have run into a problem trying to Install the ISO to the VirtualBox machine as the Install option won't install the new Linux distro to the VM.

I have tried manually partitioning and copying the folders from inside the CD image directly to the HDD but the machine won't load.

I've tried CloneZilla but it doesn't like the fact the Live CD is not a hard disk image.

Can anyone advise, I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with XFCE

Comment: Really strange this - I've used standard Ubuntu ISO - with VirtualBox and the ISO mounted perfectly through the VirtualBox configuration for my VM. Have you tried a standard ISO downloaded from the Ubuntu site?

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox a Live CD is not an installation, it runs off the ISO image. Just as on a real hardware, VBOX does not save anything to a virtual drive. Youtube has [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcw25WleOs4) demo, and probably others. You must have missed something in the configuration process.

Then there might be something with your VBOX version for your Ubuntu release OR your custom-built images. Try a different Live CD and/or a different VBOX version/host platform.

Also, do not mount your Live CD in advance, and move it from optical or USB to drive.